# Is there any way to Access the camera functionality through Appium

Tags: android, android-camera, automated-tests, appium

I am trying to automate my android application using Appium. My application has a camera functionality. Through that application, a user is able to take photos and upload it to the server. 
My Question is, I want to automate that functionality using appium. 
I am able to automate launching camera. But not able to automate the capturing. That means through the UIautomatorviewer not able to locate the capture button.
How to automate this scenario? Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the android keyevent for Camera:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_HOME
The above link contains all the keyevents but be reminded that some represent hardkeys which are not valid for every device.

An example:
driver.sendKeyEvent(27); Opens up the camera app if the device has a hardkey that opens the camera app. 
If you use this line when you are inside the camera app it will always take a shot independent of the android version/gui/device buttons.

Comment: Inside the camera, once the camera shot icon is clicked it takes to another options like approve/reject. what is the key event for approve(tick symbol) and reject(X symbol) options

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell input keyevent 27");